# Insert a horizontal line using tables in R

Tags: r, latex

I wonder if it is possible to insert a horizontal line in an arbitrary position with the `tables` package, since the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) does not explain how to achieve it.

Let's use the example in the documentation:

```r
library(tables)
tab <- tabular( (Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*
         (Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data=iris )
tab
#                Sepal.Length      Sepal.Width
# Species    n   mean         sd   mean        sd
# setosa      50 5.01         0.35 3.43        0.38
# versicolor  50 5.94         0.52 2.77        0.31
# virginica   50 6.59         0.64 2.97        0.32
# All        150 5.84         0.83 3.06        0.44
```

Then, using `latex(tab)` from the Hmisc package, one could convert the table object to LaTex, producing the following output:

[image]

Is it possible to insert a `\midrule` above the `All` row to obtain the following table?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gues you could edit the latex directly:

```r
ltab <- Hmisc::latex(tab)
ltab$text <- gsub("\nAll", "\n\\\\hline\nAll", ltab$text)
```

Now `ltab` gives the following output:

[image]

Comment: Most likely, this is the easiest way to achieve it for the example in the question. However, [Hmisc:latex returns an empty object](https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/blob/5584e4cc839d0aea0984adb87804dd40bc4aa80a/R/latex.s#L301-L304), it writes the output to stdout or to the given file using cat. Writing the table to a file and then using the regex with sed (calling it with system from R) might be the solution.

Comment: @Gorka, no, in my answer, I gave `Hmisc::latex` the `tab` object that you created, and it creates an S3 object with two members: `text` and `file`. That's why the above solution works. I didn't just make it up: that code produced that output

Comment: Yes, I am sure that you produced the output... the attached image it is a new one ;) But I am unable to reproduce it. My ltab object has two attributes (file and style) but not `text` attribute. I am using R 4.0.2 and Hmisc 4.4-0. I will try to figure out what it is happening.

Comment: Ummm... the missing `\cmidrule` below Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width in your output makes me suspect that we are using different versions.